# How to convert and round seconds to hours in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our database time is stored in seconds. I need to pull the time out and convert into hours with a max of 2 decimal places.

I have the following
sum (CAST(vt.TIMEINSECONDS AS decimal(10,2))/3600) as AMOUNT_TAKEN

for most part it works, but sometimes it shows 39.9999998 instead of 40 hrs and in the reports i'm running due to the time being like that its causing issues.  How can i get it to show 40

Answer (score 1):

CAST the result after division

```
CAST(SUM(vt.TIMEINSECONDS)/3600.0 AS decimal(10,2)) as AMOUNT_TAKEN
```

Comment: what is your value of `TIMEINSECONS` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way to the round the value for my issue.

sum (CAST(ROUND(vt.TIMEINSECONDS/60.0/60.0,2)AS decimal (6,2)))

Thank you to all that helped.